# Probability associated with experiencing all outcomes

Tags: probability, self-study, coupon-collector-problem

Assume last year I commuted to work in a taxi, and suppose if there are $n$ taxis in the fleet I used. If I took one of these taxis every trip at random and with replacement, then what is the number of trips I need to make in order to use every taxi in the fleet?

Answer (score 7):

This is the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

The expected number is $$n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$$ which is about $n(\log_e(n)+ \gamma) +\tfrac12$ where $\gamma \approx 0.577\ldots$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant. But there is a wide dispersion and you will never be absolutely sure.

Then there is the issue of what "at random" means: some taxis may usually work when you are not commuting or in other parts of the city.