# How many attempts to randomly draw all 7 cards out of 7 with replacement?

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Probability associated with no of fleet calculation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29364/probability-associated-with-no-of-fleet-calculation)

Assuming I have 7 cards (Ace - 7) shuffled, and I draw one card and replace it, reshuffle, and randomly draw another card, on average how many draws would it take to have picked each card at least once?

I have been working on this problem and I've come to the conclusion that there are 7 separate events, such that the first is a 7/7 chance that a new card is chosen, the 2nd event would be 6/7, and so on until 1/7. What I am not sure of is how to combine the events such that it yields the number of draws.

I should add that this particular answer in this example isn't as important as the "how". I would like to apply the same thinking to a different problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is called the [coupon collector problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

You are correct that you can write the number of draws as a sum of geometric random variables ("events" means something else) with success probabilities $7/7, 6/7, 5/7, ... 1/7$. By the linearity of expectation, the average number of draws is the sum of the average values of those geometric random variables, $7/7 + 7/6 + 7/5 + ... + 7/1 = 7(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/7) = 363/20 = 18.15$.

For $n$ cards in the deck instead of $7$, the average number of draws needed to collect all examples is $n \log n + \gamma n + 1/2 + o(1)$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $0.577$ by comparing the sum $\sum_i^n \frac 1i$ with the integral $\int_1^n \frac 1x dx$.