# Expectation of the number of drawings

Tags: binomial-distribution, expected-value, hypergeometric-distribution

An urn contains B black and W white balls. What is the expected number of drawings required to get a ball of each color ? With or without replacement, up to you.

With replacement, am I right to think that it is

$$2bw+3b^2w+4b^3w\cdots+2wb+3w^2b+4w^3b\cdots=bw\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+2)(b^k+w^k)=bw\left(\frac{1+w}{w^2}+\frac{1+b}{b^2}\right)=1+\frac WB+\frac BW$$
where $b$ and $w$ are the fractions of both colors ?

Comment: _Without_ replacement, the number of draws cannot exceed $\max\{B,W\} + 1$, no?

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I mean *with*.

Comment: This is the [coupon collector problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector). The search turns up many threads that provide explicit formulas.

Comment: @whuber: all entries I found are about equiprobable coupons. For two coupons, the expectation is $2H_2=3$, which matches my solution.

Comment: Many of the *methods* described in the answers apply with almost no change to varying probabilities.

Comment: @whuber: certainly not the ones that rely on the Harmonic Numbers.

Comment: Yes, even those, if you follow (*e.g.*) Douglas Zare's argument at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40797.

Answer (score 1):

*With replacement*, the urn always has $B+W$ balls. Conditioned on the first ball being Black, the (conditional) expected waiting time to get one ball of each color is $1 + \frac{B+W}{W}$ where the fraction is the expected waiting time to get a White ball. Similarly, conditioned on the first ball being White, the (conditional) expected waiting time to get one ball of each color is $1 + \frac{B+W}{B}$. Now put these answers together to get the unconditional waiting time.