# How difficult is it to collect the full set of toys from McDonald's Happy Meal?

Tags: probability

Say there are 12 different kinds of toys available and you don't know which one you'll get as a free gift when you buy a Happy Meal.

How many Happy Meals do you have to order before you can collect the whole set? Assuming the toys are allocated randomly and the number produced is the same for each toy.

Comment: Searching the site for [Coupon collector](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector) links to solutions at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29365, http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40797, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48396.  The latter delves a little more deeply into the full distribution.

Comment: This is the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem). There are many [posts on site about it](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector). (Edit: leaving this comment here even though whuber covered it, since the wikipedia link is new)